# Как ElasticSearch работает с БД?

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, elasticsearch

На хосте произошел сбой, после этого сайт перестал работать, я востановил пару классов, которые были поврежденны, сайт заработал, но разделы где испльзуется *ElasticSearch* перестал работать, выходит такая ошибка:

> CouldNotConnectToHost in AbstractConnection.php line 323:
>   Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused

Получается я немогу соединиться с БД, что бы отобразить страницу.

В логах на *hhvm* нашел такую строку:

> Fatal error: Invalid operand type was used: cannot perform this operation with arrays in /home/uzbek/uzbek.rf/www/storage/framework/views/0822cd43cbe3e1a6fe6c9cbce47c072e on line 37

Что делать?

Comment: полагаю эти логи мало связанны.

Уверены, что 127.0.0.1:9200 действительно доступен?

Comment: @Gedweb
Да, т.к. под своим прфилям я моу попасть на сайт, т.е. данные из бд подгружаеются, а именно разделы где используют elasticsearch выходит такая ошибка :(. что делать даже незнаю :(

Comment: на какой интерфейс смотрит elasticsearch  ?

Comment: База данных сайта и _elasticsearch_ это разные вещи. У _elasticsearch_ это поисковая система с собственной базой и судя по ошибкам проблема именно в подключение к _elasticsearch_. Правда на сколько я могу судить по [сайту](http://xn--90aieo5b.xn--p1ai/) проблема уже решена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch - это отдельный сервер, предназначенный для полнотекстового поиска. Судя по всему он просто не поднят после сбоя и сайт ожидает его ответов на локальном хосте по порту 9200. Убедиться в том запущен он или нет, можно при помощи команды

```
ps aux | grep elasticsearch
```

Comment: Бльшое спасибо:)